# How to suspend Fedora 39 after a given delay

Tags: linux, fedora, sleep

recently I started setting up a new Fedora 39 machine and ran into an issue where it would suspend when I boot it (using wake on lan) and then connect to SSH. I think that it doesn't register SSH as an active session like it would with a desktop session so after 15 minutes it goes to sleep.

I managed to fix the going to sleep issue by following the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1226566/297877). Essentially, it boils down to running `sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target` when an SSH session begins, and unmasking them when the final session ends. So now, after the delay I still get the system broadcast that it's going down for sleep, but after that it doesn't actually go down. For now that's fine for me.

However; once it tries to sleep once, it then never tries again. So, when I end my session after the regular suspend timer has passed, it will then just stay on forever.

Initially I figured I could modify the script from the above answer to simply wait for 5 minutes and then run `sudo systemctl sleep`, but then realized that it would put my computer to sleep even if I had logged into the desktop by that point.

So, my question is this: How can I re-enable the regular suspend timer after first stopping it by masking `sleep.target` and `suspend.target`?

Thanks!